How to disable CSS double scrolling once flex-wrap kicks in?
I created a two-column layout (CodePen), where the left column stays fixed, while the right column scrolls. Additionally, these columns wrap into a single column when the browser width is small enough. My problem is once they wrap, the second column keeps its scroll behavior, and the container scrolls too (so I have a double scroll).
My ideal situation would be that once the right column wraps under the left, the left column joins into the scroll, so there is just one single scroll.
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, forestgreen 0%, black 100%);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 90vh;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.left-fixed {
  background-color: lightpink;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
}

.right-scroll {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.big-content {
  height: 3000px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(34,193,195,1) 0%, rgba(253,187,45,1) 100%);
}

This ideal behavior can be simulated by setting right-scroll's overflow to visible once the right column wraps under the left. This will cause the single column to only have a single scroll within container.
The only thing I can think to do is somehow use javascript to detect when the wrap occurs, and switch the right columns overflow from auto to visible... but this feels clunky.
CodePen

Have you try media query?

@tacoshy, I have not copy-pasted the code from the codepens. I have just code make runable which is OP provided.

Here is a solution using media-queries. As far as I no there is no such thing as "Apply this style to this element when flex-wrap kicks in" without using JS and some layering computations.


.container {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, forestgreen 0%, black 100%);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 90vh;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.left-fixed {
    background-color: lightpink;
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
}

.right-scroll {
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.big-content {
    height: 3000px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(34,193,195,1) 0%, rgba(253,187,45,1) 100%);
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: revert;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .left-fixed {
    height: 400px;
    flex: revert;
  }
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-fixed"></div>
    <div class="right-scroll">
        <div class="big-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>




Thanks Symtox. Interesting, I hadn't tried a media query. The only thing is that I would need some way to make sure that the media query kicks in at the exact same time as the flex wrap... I'll try experimenting with it tomorrow. Thanks!

You don't have to make it kick exactly at the same time. You need it to kick in BEFORE the flex-wrap does. This is easy to achieve because you know the minimal size it requires: 2 x padding + min-width = 430. So i would expect everything above 430px to work (@media( max-width: 430px ))

from what i could understand maybe u should add
overflow:auto in .left-fixed

I don't think that does it... I think this would cause a 3rd scroll bar. But thanks for the suggestion
